# Python module not found even though its installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Does anyone else have this issue? For reference check this screenshot: [image: Error]

PIP is also up to date and I already tried reinstalling it but it didn't work neither. I'm using VS Code. It also worked just fine yesterday but today it didn't anymore for some reason.

Comment: Seems like your mss package is not in the path. One solution is to add its path to `sys.path`.

Comment: It looks like you've created a virtual environment. You need to activate your virtual environment to access the dependencies installed within it. I've only done this on linux but should be similar enough for windows. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Could you recheck the package installation using the ```pip freeze``` command on the same env you are running your code and then check whether you are importing the correct way or not i.e., ```from mss import mss``` or ```mss.mss()``` [mss doc](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html)

Comment: What command did you use to install the package?

Comment: User JialeDu helped me with his response. You can check it out if you want to fix the same problem you're having like mine.

Comment: Done :) Sorry for the delay, I'm new to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your mss package is installed locally, but you are using a virtual environment to run code.

[image]

##### Two solutions:

**1. Switch the interpreter to the local interpreter, which is the `c:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\....` in your picture**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, search for and select `Python:Select Interpreter`

  [image]
- Select the interpreter with the `mss` package installed

  [image]

**2. Install the `mss` package for your virtual environment**

- Select the virtual environment interpreter in the selection panel

  [image]
- Create a new terminal activation environment

  [image]
- Install `mss` package using command `pip install mss`

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try installing mss outside of the venv and see if that works. also check that the venv you're using is the right one according to vscode

Answer (score -1):

If you are using multiple versions of python or use any python version in appdata, without venv, you can try running "pip install mss" from elevated (administrator) cmd instance within python install directory/scripts, shown on the console image above. If it is not the right python version used in the project, same applies to any installed python version. If IDE is used check interpreter setting to determine which one is in play.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a virtual environment, you can install you package directly there. For windows:

```
py -m pip install mss
```

[More reading](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

The other solution can be to add the path of your package to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
my_pkgs_path = r'/home/.../my_pkgs'

if my_pkgs_path in sys.path:
    print('already in sys.path')
else:
    print('not found in sys.path')
    sys.path.append(my_pkgs_path)       
    print('Added to sys.path')
```

Comment: Never touch `sys.path` by hand unless you really know what you're doing and are willing to debug very strange issues.

Comment: @AKX That's a great point. Thank you very much for sharing it. Also, can you please advise whether the specific code snippet above can have any adverse consequences? My understanding is that this code adds the corresponding path to `sys.path` only for the current session. It does not have a permanent effect on `sys.path`. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The gist of it is that there are better ways of doing that - virtualenvs (or `.pth` files if you need to). For instance, if you do `import x` before manipulating `sys.path` to add a directory where there's another `x.py`, the second `x.py` won't be imported because of `sys.modules` caching things. But you're correct in that it only affects the current session.